# What happened to Ctrl-Click in Blender 2.8?

Tags: extrude

In previous versions of Blender, I was able to go into edit mode, and CTRL-Click as an extrusion shortcut. Now, in Blender 2.8, when I do this, I accidentally select other objects, even though I'm in edit mode. What changed, and how do I de-select things that have been CTRL-selected?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The extrude shortcut hasn't changed, the default select button has.

The extrude shortcut is <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+ non-select mouse button, where 2.7x defaults to <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select, you use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to extrude, Now that 2.80 has <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> select you use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> to extrude, unless you change your selection setting.

In 2.80, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> can select a different object while in edit mode. This appears to be a planned feature, it can be useful for example when adding hook modifiers that use different objects for different vertices, where the selected object is assigned to a modifier property.

Comment: I think this is the 3rd time I've had to come to this page. Old habits die hard.

Comment: can some one add edition for MacOs?